# Weird Namespace Behavior in c++

Tags: c++, string, gcc, kernel, std

Im working on an OS, and while updating my implementation of the string header (there is no libstd linked in an OS by default) I started to get a lot of errors.

In one case, my header string was included in a header called 'fat16.h' which was then included in 'filesystem.h'.
While building filesystem.cpp, which includes filesystem.h i got this error.

```
src/kernel/filesystem/filesystem.h:16:27: error: 'kstd' has not been declared
   16 | extern FHANDLE(*fileOpen)(kstd::string path);
```

Yes, the string header is included in filesystem.h and the name is correct.

string header:

```
#ifndef __K_STRING_H__
#define __K_STRING_H__

#include <functions.h>
#include <screen.h>
#include <kvector>
#include <stddef.h>

namespace kstd {

class string {
private:
    char* m_cstr;
    size_t m_size;
public:
    string() {
        m_cstr = new char[1];
        m_cstr[0] = '\0';
        m_size = 0;
    }
    
    string(const string& old) {
        m_cstr = new char[old.size() + 1];
        memcpy(m_cstr, old.c_str(), old.size() + 1);
        m_size = old.size();
    }

    string(const char* _str) {
        m_size = strlen(_str);
        m_cstr = new char[m_size+1];
        memcpy(m_cstr, _str, m_size+1);
    }   

    void operator+=(const string& _val) {
        char* newBuf = new char[_val.size() + m_size + 1];      
        memcpy(newBuf, m_cstr, m_size);
        memcpy(newBuf + m_size, _val.c_str(), _val.size() + 1);
        delete[] m_cstr;
        m_cstr = newBuf;
        m_size += _val.size();
    }

    string operator+(const string& other) {
        char* newBuf = new char[other.size() + m_size + 1];
        memcpy(newBuf, m_cstr, m_size);
        memcpy(newBuf + m_size, other.c_str(), other.size() + 1);
        return newBuf;
    }

    void operator+=(char val) {
        
        char* newBuf = new char[m_size + 2];
        
        memcpy(newBuf, m_cstr, m_size);
        newBuf[m_size] = val;
        newBuf[m_size+1] = '\0';
        m_size++;
        delete[] m_cstr;
        m_cstr = newBuf;
    }

    string& erase(size_t pos = 0, size_t len = 1) {
        char* buf = new char[m_size - len + 1];
        int a = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < m_size; i++) {
            if (i >= pos && i < pos + len) {
                continue;
            }
            buf[a] = m_cstr[i];
            a++;
        }
        m_cstr = buf;
        m_size = m_size - len;
        return *this;
    }
 
    void pop_back() {
        erase(m_size-1, 1);
    }

    void operator=(const char* other) {
        m_size = strlen(other);
        m_cstr = new char[m_size + 1];
        memcpy(m_cstr, other, m_size + 1);
    }

    void operator=(const string& other) {
        m_cstr = new char[other.size() + 1];
        memcpy(m_cstr, other.c_str(), other.size() + 1);
        m_size = other.size();
    }

    bool operator== (const string& other) {
        // if they both dont have the same size then they cant be equal
        if (other.size() != m_size)
            return false;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < m_size; i++) {
            // if there is ever a character that doesnt match
            if (other[i] != m_cstr[i])
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    char& operator[] (size_t index) {
        return m_cstr[index];
    }

    const char& operator[] (const size_t index) const {
        return m_cstr[index];
    }

    char* c_str() const {
        return m_cstr;
    }

    size_t size() const {
        return m_size;
    }

    ~string() {
        delete[] m_cstr;        
    }
};



}

static ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, kstd::string val) {
    out.print(val.c_str());
    return out;
}


#endif
```

filesystem.h

```
#ifndef FILESYSTEM_H
#define FILESYSTEM_H

#include "fat16.h"

// general file handle
#ifndef FHANDLE
#define FHANDLE void*
#endif

enum FileSys {
    FAT16
};

// returns a handle to the file that can later be used to do I/O with the file
extern FHANDLE(*fileOpen)(kstd::string path);

// frees all allocated data and should be called after all file IO is done to a file, after this, the file handle becomes invalid and must not be used again
extern void(*fileClose)(FHANDLE file);

// reads from the file handle file, into the buffer buf, with a size of sz, starting from the offset offset
extern void(*fileRead)(FHANDLE file, char* buf, uint32_t size, uint32_t offset);

// returns size of the file
extern uint32_t(*fileSize)(FHANDLE file);


// initalizes whichever file system the computer is running
void initFS();

FileSys getFS();


#endif
```

includes of fat16.h:

```
#include <kvector>
#include <kstring>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <functions.h>
#include <diskATA.h>
#include <screen.h>
```

Comment: I don't know what you expect people to be able to tell you about code you aren't showing them.

Comment: I forgot to add the files, my bad

Comment: Maybe try running your compiler in such a way that it shows you what `filesystem.cpp` looks like after all the includes? In G++ that's `-E`. Right now there's a huge amount of unknown files that might be having some effect or another. Like, to pick a deliberately silly example, what if `kvector` has `#define __K_STRING_H__` or something in there? Please try to cut this down to a _minimal, reproducible_ example